# A simple yet tricky equation to solve in econometrics

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question is rather simple: I'm looking for the value of $M$ for which the following equation holds:

$ f^{(-1)}(1-\frac{d*b}{M*a})*b*e+\sqrt{a*c*b} = a*M$ or even simpler:

$ a*M- f^{(-1)}(1-\frac{d*b}{M*a})*b*e+\sqrt{a*c*b} = 0$

Important to know is that $a, b, c, d$ and $e$ are all constants and a closed form expression for $M$ wants to be found. It seems simple, but I just keep struggling with the inverse cumulative distribution function of the normal distribution (ICDF) $ f^{(-1)}(x)$, where the CDF is ofcourse:

$f(x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{e^{-t^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\;\mathrm{d}t$

where $t$ is the standardized value $\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$

As you can see, my variable $M$ is in that density function as well it is outside. I've tried solving it with the following approximations for the ICDF:

$ f^{-1}(x) = -5.5310{[[(1-x)/x]^{0.1193} - 1 ]}$

$ f^{-1}(x) = -0.4115{[[(1-x)/x]+ln[(1-x)/x] - 1 ]}$

, where $x$ is $1-\frac{d*b}{M*a}$

But I haven't found a solution yet. Anyone got some creativity or possible solution/good approximation for $M$ in this equation?

Comment: Given how the errfunc is involved, I won't expect anything more practical than numerical methods

Comment: I am afraid that that will be the outcome indeed, @HagenvonEitzen . I hope someone sees something we don't see.

Comment: Perhaps the iteration $$ M_{n+1} = \frac 1a\cdot \frac {db}{1-f\left(\frac{aM_n-\sqrt{abc}}{be}\right)}$$ converges somewhat fast enough?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen that's definitely a good numerical solution. It converges pretty fast. Wonder how you arrived to that. You can put this as an official answer, I'll definitely'd power it up.